# rails app grab info from another table for each index

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new Rails so thanks for assisting

I would like to when the rails app shows all Posts, use the user_i tod grab info from another table, the employer_info table

As an example I've done a similar thing with the show action/view.

Post controller

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @employer_info = @post.user.employer_info
end
```

It uses the user_id stored in the post table to look up the corresponding employer_info

The corresponding models

```
class EmployerInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :user
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :posts
  has_one       :employer_info
end
```

Corresponding views

```
Show page
<%= @post.title %>
<%= @post.body %>
<%= @employer_info.name %>

Index Page
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
<%= link_to p.title, p %>
<% end %>
```

For the index page I would like each post list to also grab the name from the user_info table similar to the show action

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will help.

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
  <%= link_to p.title, p %>
  <%= p.user.employer_info %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also reading some info about `includes` method: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes